# $state.go redirects to old URL not changing the state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm facing this issue with state.go not working as expected

Below is how various states are defined

```
(function (app) {
  'use strict';

  app.ng.requires.push('ui.bootstrap');
  //app.ng.requires.push('ngGrid');
  app.ng.requires.push('ui.router');
  app.ng.requires.push('ngTouch');
  app.ng.requires.push('ngAnimate');

  app.ng.run(
  ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    debugger;
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
  }
  ]
  );
  app.ng.config(
  ['$stateProvider',
  function ($stateProvider) {
    debugger;
    var modulePath = 'modules/listBuild';
    var ctrlRoot = app.root + modulePath + '/Views/';   
    $stateProvider
    .state('recipe',
    {
      url: '#recipe',
      templateUrl: ctrlRoot + 'selectRecipe.html'
    })
    .state('selectLocation',
    {
      url: '#selectLocation',
      templateUrl: ctrlRoot + 'selectLocation.html'
    })
 }]);

}(window.app));
```

and click event to change the view using state.go

```
scope.goToListbuild = function () {             
            timeout(function () {
                location.path('/' + sessionSvc.get('clientKey') + '/' + sessionSvc.get('orgKey') + '/lists/build');
                state.go('recipe');         
            }, 10);
};
```

now when ever the session value changes the user should be redirected to different paths. what currently happening is even if the session value changes the state.go takes it to older URL.

I tried differenet options of state.go and state.reload but it doesn't work

So if this is the changed URL of Home page  "/PQR/PQR-sec1/lists" where i click the link it actually goes back to "/ABC/ABC-sec1/lists/build#recipe" instead of "/PQR/PQR-sec1/lists/build#recipe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you a bad url defined for your state define for example :

```
$stateProvider
  .state('recipe',
  {
     url: '/recipe', //url which looks like myDomain.com/#/recipe 
     templateUrl: ctrlRoot + 'selectRecipe.html'
  })
  .state('selectLocation',
  {
     url: '/selectLocation',
     templateUrl: ctrlRoot + 'selectLocation.html'
  });
```

But i suggest that you use "ui-sref" in your html because I think you change it onClick so juste use something like this

```
  <a ui-sref="recipe"> </a>
```

If it doesn't work try to comment your line `location.path(...)`

Comment: I don't think i would be able to use the ui-sref as it's conditional and got to use the changed location before i could use state.go()... what i really want to know if anything which can reload the path

Comment: i changed location.path with window.location.href and it worked but i really don't think i would use that hack, but it will help somebody to suggest something on that lines

Comment: That helped me :) Thanks